# Prevent TinyMCE adding a space to the <!--[if lt IE9]> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, tinymce

I am in the unfortunate situation of having to provide support for IE8 and I am loading html5shiv and respondjs into the `<head>` to deal with this.

However, I have to load all my header and footer code in a TinyMCE 4 editor instance. And TinyMCE seems to have a mind-boggling issue where it adds a space into the conditional where by:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
```

becomes:

```
<!-- [if lt IE 9]>
```

after I save it, and the one little added space between the - and the [ breaks the conditional so the html5shiv and respondjs scripts inside it are never included.

Is there any way to fix this without directly modifying the TinyMCE init script? (as I have no control over that).

Would it matter if I just loaded the scripts without the conditionals (on all browsers)? What effect would they have on other non-IE browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered TinyMCE do have an option for this, passed into the `tinymce.init` function.

```
protect: [/\<!--\[.*\]\>/g, /\<!\[.*\]--\>/g]
```

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:protect